# Não captura os eventos após clonar - jquery bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3

Estou usando o código abaixo para clonar o accordion. Mas ao tentar expandir o accordion que foi clonado o evento capturado aciona o accordion pai. Sei que o evento clone é limitado mas como resolver esse problema?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-add-panel">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Novo
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $template = $(".panel-default");

    var hash = 1;
    $(".btn-add-panel").on("click", function () {
        hash++
        var $newPanel = $template.clone(true).insertAfter($template);
        $newPanel.find(".panel-heading").attr("id", "heading-" + hash);
        $newPanel.find("a").attr("href", "#collapse-" + hash).attr("aria-controls", "collapse-" + hash).attr("class", "collapsed").attr("aria-expanded", "false")
        $newPanel.find(".panel-collapse").attr("id", "collapse-" + hash).attr("aria-labelledby", "heading-" + hash).attr("aria-expanded", "false").removeClass("in");
        $("#accordion").append($newPanel.fadeIn());
        $("#collapse-" + hash).css({ 'height:': '0px'})
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Poderia colocar um exemplo no jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelos atributos do seu `HTML`, e sabendo que está utilizando `Bootstrap CSS`.

O que está acontecendo é que:

Para o plugin ***collapse*** o Bootstrap CSS usa dois identificadores principais pra dizer qual será o target:

```
[data-toggle="collapse"] -> Para o trigger
```

E

```
[data-parent="' + this.options.parent + '"] -> Para identificar onde será feito trigger
```

No seu caso, está faltando modificar o valor de `'parent'`, para que ele identifique corretamente onde será feito o `'collapse'`.

Basta adicionar `'.attr("data-parent","#collapse-" + hash);'` ao ***$newPanel***;

```
$newPanel.find("a").attr("href", "#collapse-" + hash).attr("aria-controls", "collapse-" + hash).attr("class", "collapsed").attr("aria-expanded", "false").attr("data-parent","#collapse-" + hash);
```

E por fim, adicione um identificador para dizer qual elemento será o que vai acabar sendo clonado, e utilize ***appendTo*** no lugar de ***insertAfter*** , o método appendTo irá colocar dentro, enquanto insertAfter irá acrescentar depois, perdendo o estrutura.

No exemplo a seguir utilizei um classname `'to-copy'` que é removido do objeto do novo elemento gerado após o `appendTo`, copiando sempre o mesmo.

Exemplo funcional:

```js
var $template = $(".panel-default");

    var hash = 1;
    $(".btn-add-panel").on("click", function () {
        hash++
        var $newPanel = $template.clone().appendTo($template);
        
        
        $newPanel.removeClass('to-copy');
            
        $newPanel.find(".panel-heading").attr("id", "heading-" + hash);
        
        //Aqui foi feito modificações, adicionado o ultimo método
        $newPanel.find("a").attr("href", "#collapse-" + hash).attr("aria-controls", "collapse-" + hash).attr("class", "collapsed").attr("aria-expanded", "false").attr("data-parent","#collapse-" + hash);
        
        $newPanel.find(".panel-collapse").attr("id", "collapse-" + hash).attr("aria-labelledby", "heading-" + hash).attr("aria-expanded", "false").removeClass("in");
        $("#accordion").append($newPanel.fadeIn());
        $("#collapse-" + hash).css({ 'height:': '0px'})
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-add-panel">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Novo
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default to-copy">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Boa tarde anthraxisbr, o código ainda continua com o mesmo problema. Ao clicar nas clonadas o evento aciona a pai. O evento só irá para o accordion correto se o accordion pai não estiver expandido, mas isso só acontece para o primeiro clone.

Comment: @RonaldoPeixoto não prestei atenção na hora que coloquei o codigo ali, acabei de arrumar, se resolver o seu problema basta aceitar a resposta ;D

Comment: Muito obrigado, sua solução resolveu o problema. Já estava há horas em busca de uma solução.